# Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

I am working on a Django project as a Front-End developer. I am getting **" django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "13.234.81.119", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)

Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?"**
many times when I try to run the server using the command `python manage.py runserver` on `VS Code`

Because of this, I have to restart the server, and sometimes luckily server works.
I did the following things to resolve the problem:

**NOTE: I am using windows 11.**

**1)** deleted temporary files using the command `%temp%`

**2)** reinstalled psycopg 2.9.2

**3)** I reset the TCP/IP settings in services on my PC.

but the problem did not solve.

I am attaching the screenshots of the complete error log. Please help me to resolve the issue, I will be grateful to you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your Postgres running on the port you specified if not?

Go inside the bin folder in the C drive where Postgres is installed. run the following command in git bash or Command prompt:

```
pg_ctl.exe restart -D "<path upto data>"
```

Example

```
pg_ctl.exe restart -D  "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data"
```